# Does Python 3.3's support of xz-compressed zipfiles extend to zipimport?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, python-import

Python 3.3's zipfile module understands .zip archives that have been compressed with bzip2 or xz instead of the traditional deflate algorithm. Does this extended compression support extend to the zipimport functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the [`zipimport.c` source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/zipimport.c) is implemented independently from the stdlib `zipfile` module and only supports ZLIB compressed data or uncompressed archives.

Specifically, the heavy lifting is done in the [`get_data` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/zipimport.c#l1026) which has `/* data is not compressed */` and `/* Decompress with zlib */` branches.